# Actions inside Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a masterpage inside a Area and a Controller outside the area. The controller's called "SecurityController" and i'm calling <%= Url.Action("LogOut", "Security", new {area=""}) %> as i saw in some posts but that doens't map to my "root" controllers.
The link is generated for /AREANAME/SecurityController/ witch's wrong.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank U all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the behavior you are describing. Here are the steps I did:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project using the default template
2. Add a new area called `AREANAME` using the Visual Studio Wizard
3. Add a FooController inside `~/Areas/AREANAME/Controller/FooController.cs`:

   ```
   public class FooController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Copy-Paste the master page from `~/Views/Shared/Site.Master` to `~/Areas/AREANAME/Views/Shared/Site.Master`
5. Add a new `Index` view corresponding to the `Index` action of the `FooController` using the master page. Leave it as default.
6. Somewhere inside the master page of the area add the following (or inside the Index view of the FooController, it doesn't really matter):

   ```
   <%= Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" }) %>
   ```
7. Run the site and navigate to `/AREANAME/foo/index`.
8. The correct url is generated: `/`

If you remove the `area=""` part of the helper the following url is generated: `/AREANAME/Home`.

So?

Comment: Hi Darin... i'll try that now.

Comment: Hi Darin... your example works like a charm!! i'll see what i'm doing wrong in my project... tell you when have conclusion. Thanks

Comment: Darin... Thank U verry much. I've lost some hours in this "issue" but the problem was indeed a routing problem. I've wrote a route that matches a Area, so the actionlink always map my area instead my "root". Sorry for your time but you indeed helped me in this one ;) Thanks